# How to compare one Map keyset with another Map's field-value?

Tags: apex, map

I am trying to compare a map that contains Contact ids to the Map that holds `ContactId` as one of the fields that I have queried in each key-value pairs.

```
Map<Id, Contact> relatedContIdsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>(selectedContacts);
Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole> relatedOppConRoleMap = 
                    new Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole>([Select Id, ContactId 
                                                        From OpportunityContactRole
                                                        Where OpportunityId 
                                                        IN :relatedOppMap.keySet() ]);
```

How can I have a condition to compare the ContactIds of the map: `relatedContIdsMap` to the ContactIds that are retrieved in the map: `relatedOppConRoleMap`.

I have come across this: [containsKey(key)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) from the developer docs, which seems to compare the actual key of a map, but not a particular field inside a map.

Comment: Just to double check are you asking how to compare values of two maps that has the same keys?

Comment: Nope. From above maps, each map has a separate key(one with ContactId, one with OpportunityContactRole's Id). Now trying to compare the first map's key(ContactId) to the second map's field(ContactId) to see if the second map contains the particular contact record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not without iterating over the values of your `relatedOppConRoleMap` (which, at first glance, kinda defeats the purpose of storing your `OpportunityContactRole`s in a map in the first place).

To get around this issue, you can simply iterate over your query results and build your map by yourself (instead of using the map constructor).

```
Map<Id, Contact> relatedContIdsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>(selectedContacts);
Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole> relatedOppConRoleMap = new Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole>();

for(OpportunityContactRole ocr :[Select Id, ContactId From OpportunityContactRole Where OpportunityId IN :relatedOppMap.keySet()]){
    relatedOppConRoleMap.put(ocr.ContactId, ocr);
}

// You can now access the OCR records based on the contactId
for(Contact cont :relatedContIdsMap.values()){
    OpportunityContactRole myOCR = relatedOppConRoleMap.get(cont.Id);
}

// ...or do other operations, like getting rid of all of the OCRs for 
//   Contacts that you didn't previously select
relatedOppConRoleMap.keySet().retainAll(relatedContIdsMap.keySet());
```

Comment: Seems like a promising approach to work my way around. I will keep you posted with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

Derek F's answer is the right answer for your situation; however, I have had a similar situation in the past where I needed to find the differences between to SObject maps and do work on the end result. For my need I created the following:

### Sample

```
public static Map<Object, SObject> getMapDiff(Map<Id, SObject> map1, Map<Id, SObject> map2) {
    Map<Id, SObject> result = new Map<Id, SObject>();

    for (Id i : map1.keySet()) {
        if (!map2.containsKey(i)) {
            result.put(i, map1.get(i));
        }
    }

    for (Id i : map2.keySet()) {
        if (!map1.containsKey(i)) {
            result.put(i, map2.get(i));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This generates a map of SObjects that are only present in 1 of the two maps. I honestly forgot exactly why I needed it to be this way but I wanted to get this out there in case anyone needed something like it for any weird reason. This is more of a last resort approach.